# Mockito - Feeling that I don't use its full potential

Tags: java, junit, mockito

When using Mockito, I only use it to mock out dependencies, i.e. my workflow looks mostly like this:

I have a class with dependencies:

```
public class C {
    public C (A a, B b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public String fooBar() {
        return a.foo() + b.bar();
    }
}
```

In my test class, I mock out those dependencies, and tell them which values to return when some specified methods are called:

```
public class CSpec {
    private A a = mock(A.class);
    private B b = mock(B.class);

    @Test
    public itShouldReturnFooBar() {
        when(a.foo()).thenReturn("foo");
        when(b.bar()).thenReturn("bar");

        C c = new C(a, b);

        assertThat(c.fooBar().isEqualTo("foobar"));
    }
}
```

(I hope this example is not too simple or too derived ;-)). This works fine, it allows me to test classes (here: C) in isolation. Still, I never use Mockito's `verify` methods or any other of its features. Is it okay / sufficient to use Mockito this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Verify would be typically used to check that your `C` really calls the A.foo() and B.bar() methods. So you could add

```
verify(a).foo();
verify(b).foo();
```

before or after the assertThat. I don't think you need or should use them here but there are several situations where you would need that:

- a or b does something that is not visible / reachable from c's public API (for example logging)
- You are concerned with the order of execution
- You want to make sure that *only* `a.foo` and `b.bar` methods are called, nothing else like `a.foo2`
- You could use those mocks as spy's, so that call to `a.foo` would be then routed to the `aReal.foo`

Comment: But does it really buy me anything? Isn't checking the returned value enough?

Comment: What if your method doesn't return a value?

Comment: In your very simple case yes, but in many cases checking that something is really called during execution of a complex method is exactly what you want.

Comment: Don't use `verify` in a test like this.  You're correctly testing that `foobar` returns the correct value.  On the other hand, if `foo` and `bar` didn't return values, or if you didn't use those values in any way, then you'd probably want to use `verify` to check that they actually called.  In general, tests will EITHER verify that something happened, OR make assertions about a return value - if you end up doing both, you could well be trying to test too many things within one test method.

Answer (score 2):

The `verify` approach is particularly useful in a [Tell Don't Ask](http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask) style of programming.

Consider the following version of your class C:

```
public class C {
  public C(A a, B b, CListener L) { ... }
  ...
  public void foobar() {
    String result = complexPrivateMethod(a, b);
    L.fooBarred(result);
  }
}
```

Thus, rather than just computing the result, you inform some interested party (e.g. a user interface) about the result.

To test foobar now, you'd want to verify that the listener is correctly invoked:

```
public class CTest {
   @Mock CListener mockListener;
   ...

   @Test itShouldTellCAboutFooBar() {
      C c = new C(stubbedA, stubbedB, mockedListener);
      ...
      verify(mockedListener).fooBarred("foobar");
   }  
}
```

This use of `verify` is typical for Test-Driven Development: See Freeman & Pryce's [Growing Object-Oriented Software Guided by Tests](http://www.growing-object-oriented-software.com/).

Thus, if you want to *use the full potential* of Mockito (the question), you most of all need to adopt the corresponding design philosophy in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, there's no problem with this test, it's perfectly fine. The simple fact the the stubs are being used make the test working, if you remove or change the stubs then the test won't work.

Adding verify statements will just make things redundant in this kind of tests.

However if you precisely want to verify arguments, the order or number of interactions or something else then you definitely want to add checks on the interactions between the tested object and his collaborators.

Answer (score 1):

It is totally ok to use Mockito just this way. But if your code gets more complex you need to do some more things to get your code tested as simple as possible.

Another small example:

```
public void eitherAorB() {
    if(somethingIsTrue) {
        a.doSomething();
    } else {
        b.doSomethingElse();
    }
}
```

You might want to make sure, that the expected method is called on the expected object.

```
@Test
public doSomethingShouldBeCalledOnA() {
    A a = mock(A.class);
    C c = new C(a, new B());

    c.setSomeThingIsTrue(true);
    eitherAorB();

    verify(a).doSomething();
}

@Test
public doSomethingElseShouldBeCalledOnB() {
    B b = mock(B.class);
    C c = new C(new A(), b);

    c.setSomeThingIsTrue(false);
    eitherAorB();

    verify(b).doSomethingElse();
}
```

In other cases you might want to know which paramater was passed into a method. For that you need an ArgumentCaptor.

Or in some cases you need to call the actual method or use an actual object (no mock), so it is time to spy on an object and capture arguments or verify behavior.

So there is a lot more to Mockito you might need once in a while.

Answer (score 1):

The answers given so far are good, but there are additional features you didn't mention either.  The `@Mock, @Spy, @InjectMocks` annotations are all very useful.  Along with the `verify(...)` methods, there is also the InOrder class to help verify the order of method calls.  And perhaps you use the matcher methods already (`<T> any(T t), anyString()`, etc), but you don't show that you use those facilities.

Comment: Definitely worth mentioning `@Mock` - it makes things shorter and more readable.  So the first line of your test class would be `@Mock private A a;` instead of `private A a = mock(A.class);`.